# Selenium Java - How to Select a Dropdown Element that Has No ID

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium - Java WebDriver (ChromeDriver) as a new user.

While trying to select an item from a dropdown menu using Java, I couldn't do it because of the error message. Please note that I've tried variations of Select and WebElement options but not having the expected result: clicking the link from the drop down menu that should take me to the target page.

Here is the error message shown in eclipse:

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Payment"}

Here is the relevant code segment:

```
Select dropdown2 = new Select(webDriver.findElement(By.linkText("Payment")));
dropdown2.selectByVisibleText("Payment");
```

I have also tried the following with no success:

```
WebElement element = webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[class='glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card']"));
element.click();
```

Also, the following code that didn't work:

```
WebElement element = webDriver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Payment"));
Select mySelect= new Select(element);
mySelect.selectByVisibleText("Payment");
```

The segment of html is shown below:

[image: code segment]

Hoping to get feedback.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm seeing in provided screenshot HTML, this is not a `<select>` element, so you can't use `Select()` class here to work with dropdown.

You should try using simple finder with `WebDriverWait` as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);

//First click on dropdown down to open options
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("li.dropdown > a.dropdown-toggle"))).click();

//Now select opened option
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("ul.dropdown-menu > li > a[href*='Billing']"))).click();
```

Or

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Payment"))).click();
```

Or

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("Payment"))).click();
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback Saurabh. Unfortunately, I get error message with either of the coding options. With linkText, error message is: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.cssSelector: li.dropdown.open > a.dropdown-toggle[data-toggle='dropdown'] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval) ........Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"li.dropdown.open > a.dropdown-toggle[data-toggle='dropdown']"}

Comment: Using cssSelection (first option), I get the following error: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.cssSelector: li.dropdown.open > a.dropdown-toggle[data-toggle='dropdown'] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)  .......Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"li.dropdown.open > a.dropdown-toggle[data-toggle='dropdown']"}

Comment: @mkarim Try once to open dropdown using `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("li.dropdown > a.dropdown-toggle"))).click();
` and let me know

Comment: Hi Saurabh, now no error message is observed, however, it only opens the drop down menu but does not click the first option in the drop down menu.

Comment: Ok, now I have added the following line of code that clicked the desired link: webDriver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Payment")).click();

Comment: Thanks Saurabh for helping me. I am now able to click the option item from a drop down menu. I wanted to give "arrow up" for this post but looks like because I don't have sufficient points, I cannot give the point.

Comment: You can accept the answer by clicking in check mark which appears below besides the answer. [Follow this link to know that how does accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Thanks

Comment: Thank you for guiding me on this. I have just accepted the answer.